# Set Windows-Forms ComboSox DataSource to specific attributes of objects in a List

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, toolstrip

I have a List of Accounts:

```
List<Account> accountList;
```

Each Account has a `ID`.

I want to set all of the `Account`s `ID`s in the `accountList` into a Windows-Forms `ComboBox`. How can I achieve that?

## EDIT

Soultion using `Linq`:

```
myCombobox.DataSource = accountList.Select(x => x.ID);
```

Comment: Post your `Account` definition and explain when the `Account` constructor is called, what calls it, what is `Bank`, why `Bankaccountlist` is `static` and why the `Accout` object should know about its existence.

Comment: @Jimi `Account` and `Bank` are also different classes. I don't know why `Bankaccountlist` has to be `static`, but with all my other code only works when it's `static`. I have a `function` in `Bank` which creates an `Account`, but I define `Account` in `Account`. I shouldn't have named the `Class` and the `Constructor` the same, pretty stupid from my part.

Comment: The class constructor needs to have the same name as the class object it builds. That's not the point. It looks like `Bank` is a Form and you're setting that collection as static to you use it in some other classes without using DataBindings or passing a reference. If `Bank.Bankaccountlist` (static or not, badly built or not) is a collection of `Account` objects, it's not possible that setting a ComboBox DataSource, you end up showing these `_012_Bank_Programm_Forms.Account` as the Item text if the Account object has an `id` property and the `DisplayMember` has been set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `ID`'s to the Combobox with a foreach loop:

```
foreach (Account account in accountList) 
{
    comboboxName.Items.Add(account.id);
}
```

If you want the items being added at the start of the application, write the code in the constructor of your forms class:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WriteIdIntoCombobox();
}
```

I put the foreach into the `WriteIdIntoCombobox()` method so that I could call it somewhere else in the code if I needed to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DataSource property as below. Here `id` is the propertyname which you want to display in the combobox.

```
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = Bank.Bankaccountlist;
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "id";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sadly, it doesn't work, it just shows "_012_Bank_Programm_Forms.Account". `toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "id";`does nothing, if I comment it out, it does exactly the same.

Comment: Did you set the display member property? Showing "_012_Bank_Programm_Forms.Account" means the item is of that type. Setting the DisplayMember should work here.If possible can share the code here?